# HTML canvas is removed from PDF in Laravel

Tags: php, pdf, canvas, laravel-5

I am developing a Website using PHP Laravel framework.My website needs to implement a feature for generating PDF report. In that PDF report, I am drawing a picture on the HTML canvas. I am using [this library](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf) for generating PDF report. I can generate the report, the problem is canvas is not included in the report.

This is my controller generating PDF report and show it in the browser.

```
class ReportController extends Controller
{
    //
    function invoice(){
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('report.invoice');
        return $pdf->stream();
    }
}
```

This is my view file for pdf report.

```
<h1>Report</h1>
<table border="1" style="width: 100%;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Title 1</td>
            <td>1000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Title 2</td>
            <td>200</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="200">
</canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var center_x = 200;
    var center_y = 100;
    var width = 100;
    var height = 200;
    drawOvalShape(context, 200, 100, 100, 200);
    drawOvalShape(context, 200, 100, 80, 180);
    drawOvalShape(context, 200, 100, 60, 160);
    drawOvalShape(context, 200, 100, 40, 140);
    drawOvalShape(context, 200, 100, 20, 120);


    function drawOvalShape(context, center_x, center_y, width, height){
        context.beginPath();
        context.ellipse(center_x, center_y, width, height,  90 * Math.PI/180, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        context.stroke();
    }


</script>
```

But when it is displayed in the browser, the HTML canvas is removed from the report. But other html elements are working as expected. Why is it removed? How can I include the canvas in my PDF report? What is wrong with my code?

I also set html5parser to true in dompdf.php config file like this as well

```
 "DOMPDF_ENABLE_HTML5PARSER" => true,
```

It is not just working.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) doesn't really support HTML5 elements like `<canvas>` but anyway there's an [option](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/blob/master/src/Options.php#L199) to enable its experimental support

```
$dompdf->set_option('isHtml5ParserEnabled', true);
```

Maybe you can try it and check if is working for you.

Comment: I tried this as well. setIsHtml5ParserEnabled(true). Not working